# Excel conditon if column a consist in column b

Tags: excel

In excel, how can we return true or false in a column based on comparing 2 columns in each cell. for an example
we have a table looks like this in excel

```
ROW
Column : A      |   B     |   C   | 
1        apple      motor    
2        pineapple  train    
3        car        plane    
4        motor      durian
```

in the given example of the table above.
in column C , first row should return true followed by false. i know we can compare directly using

```
=if(b1=a4,TRUE,FALSE)
```

in the first column , this will return true . but i want compare each cell in column b to column a. i have tried this in excel but its returning false instead of true

```
=if(b1=a1:a4,True,false)
```

What approach should i use ?

Comment: COUNTIF? MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array formula with `OR`:

```
=OR(B1=A:A)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

Or if you don't want to use an array formula, use `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>0
```

[image]